# given $E_1, E_2, E_3, ....$ prove that the measure of {$x \in X :$ x belongs to infinite number of sets $E_k$} is $0$

Tags: measure-theory

Say I have  a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$  over a set $X$ and a measure $\mu$.

Let $E_1, E_2, E_3, .... \in \mathcal{A}$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu(E_k)$ < $\infty$.

let B = {$x \in X :$ x belongs to infinite number of sets $E_k$}.

I managed to show that B $\in \mathcal A$. I also believe that $\mu(B)=0$, But I couldn't prove it. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm not 100% sure that $\mu(B)=0$ but it makes sense, since $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu(E_k)<\infty$. If this is not true than I'd be happy if you could give me a counterexample.

Comment: This is the easy direction of the Borel-Cantelli Lemma.  For each $m$, show that $\mu(B) \le  \sum_{k=m}^\infty \mu(E_k)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$B = \bigcap_{n\geq 1} \bigcup_{k\geq n}E_k$$

so $B\in\mathcal{A}$ and

$$\mu(B) \leq \mu(\bigcup_{k\geq n}E_k) \leq \sum_{k\geq n}\mu(E_k)$$ for any $n$

Answer (score 1):

Using the Fatou Lemma,

$$
\mu\left( \bigcap_{n =1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty E_k \right)
= \mu\left( \liminf_{n\to\infty} \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty E_k \right)
\le \liminf_{n\to\infty} \mu\left(  \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty E_k \right)
\le \liminf_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=n}^\infty \mu\left(  E_k \right) = 0
$$